# WPF ComboBox Mvvm binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to get selected value from list into the command. Is there simple way to bind commandparameter to selected item?

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-56,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Time}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
```

When i tried something like

```
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}},Path=SelectionBoxItem}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
```

it's strange stuck why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Combo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-56,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Time}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Combo, Path=SelectedItem}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
```

if you give your combo box a name you can use the `ElementName` binding and bind to the Path `SelectedItem`